# Using rememberCoroutineScope() vs LaunchedEffect

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-compose

#### Context

In Jetpack compose, we have the option of using `rememberCoroutineScope()` as well as using the `LaunchedEffect` composable in order to use coroutines / run suspend functions (show snackbars etc).

The convention I've adopted so far is to remember a single coroutine scope at the top of my compose tree, and pass it down via function arguments to places where it is needed. This vaguely seems like a good practice, but on the other hand it's adding extra noise to my function signatures.

#### Questions

1. Are there any reasons for preferring the use of `LaunchedEffect` over `rememberCoroutineScope()` inside composable functions?
2. Is it worth the effort to only create / remember a coroutine scope once per compose tree, or should I just call `rememberCoroutineScope()` in each function where a coroutine is actually launched?

Comment: I know #1 was discussed on Kotlinlang Slack recently, but Slack's search is pathetic, so I can't find it. For #2, the issue is not "worth the effort" but what the right answer is for the coroutine. For example, you write `AboutScreen()` and have in there a `Text()` that shows the number of seconds since the app was built, and you use a coroutine to update the state for that `Text()`. The user visits the about screen, then leaves and uses other portions of your app for an hour.

Comment: Should your every-second coroutine be running through that whole hour, even though the about screen is not in your composition? If the answer is "heck, no", then you need a `CoroutineScope` that is scoped to the relevant composable, and that would be `rememberCoroutineScope()` in that composable. If for some reason you *do* need that coroutine to keep running, you need a scope that matches the desired lifetime. This is no different than any other coroutine scope decision: it's not about what's easy, but what is the proper lifetime for the coroutine to execute.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to look at Kotlinlang Slack. For #2, all the screens/fragments in my app have separate compose trees, so the lifetime is at most as long as a user spends on one screen. But I was thinking more about short lived things, like showing snackbars and running animations. Should I be reusing the same coroutine scope for many different short lived things, or create a new one each time? It sounds like what you're saying is that I should make the scopes no larger than necessary, which leans towards creating/remembering the coroutine scopes separately in each place they're used.

Comment: "I should make the scopes no larger than necessary" -- within reason, yes. Going back to your question, "Is it worth the effort to only create / remember a coroutine scope once per compose tree", the answer is "no". Coroutine scopes are cheap, and remembering things is cheap, so there is no need to artificially restrict your use of them. You can instead focus on what the business logic says their lifetime should be.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'd accept this as the answer if you want to make it into one.

Comment: Given the title of your question, my comments won't really be an answer. You really need the `LaunchedEffect` side of matters for that.

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/jetpack-compose-side-effects-launchedeffect-59d2330d7834 - Blog post on LaunchedEffect and rememberCoroutineScope

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Leaving my understanding here:

**Question 1:**
`LaunchedEffect` should be used when you want that some action must be taken when your composable is first launched/relaunched (or when the key parameter has changed). For example, when you want to request some data from your ViewModel or run some sort of animation...
`rememberCoroutineScope` on the other hand, is specific to store the Coroutine scope allowing the code to launch some `suspend` function...
imho, the only relation between them is that you can also use a `LaunchedEffect` to launch a coroutine...

**Question 2:** As you can see in the docs, `rememberCoroutineScope` will keep the reference of the coroutine's scope in a specific point of the composition. Therefore, if a given composable is removed from the recomposition, that coroutine will be cancelled automatically. For instance, you have the following composable calls `A -> B -> C`. If you remember the coroutine scope in `C` and it is removed from the composition, the coroutine is automatically cancelled. But if you remember from `A`, pass the scope through `B` and `C`, use this scope in `C`, and then `C` is removed, the coroutine will continue running (because it was remembered in `A`)...

Comment: Addendum: I'm using AS Arctic Fox Canary 12 and now seeing explicit warnings against using `coroutineScope.launch { ... }` inside a composable function: "Calls to launch should happen inside a LaunchedEffect and not composition." (The lint name is "CoroutineCreationDuringComposition"). So for what it's worth, this gives an 'official' directive that my previous way of using a coroutineScope for everything was not the preferred way.

Comment: rememberCoroutineScope is to launch a coroutine outside a composable within a composition-aware scope. For inside composables, coroutines should be launched with LaunchedEffect

Comment: If you write coroutineScope.launch { ... } in a Composable function, it will launch on every recomposition!

Answer (score 11):

**Use rememberCoroutineScope()** when you are using coroutines and need to
cancel and relaunch the coroutine after an event

**Use LaunchedEffect()** when you are using coroutines and need to cancel and
relaunch the coroutine every time your parameter changes and it isn’t stored in a
mutable state.

Added code here.

```
 val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
 Row(modifier = Modifier
        .clickable {  scope.launch { /* call suspend */ } } {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = key){
      /* call suspend when entering or key changed */
      }
 }
```

An interesting thing is I saw many lines of code as the below.

```
 val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
 Row(modifier = Modifier){
     LaunchedEffect(key1 = key){
        scope.launch{
         /* call suspend when entering or key changed */
        }
     }
 }
```

However, I don't think we need an extra scope in this case.

```
 Row(modifier = Modifier){
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = key){
     /* call suspend when entering or key changed */
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

> **LaunchedEffect: run suspend functions in the scope of a composable**
>
> To call suspend functions safely from inside a composable, use the LaunchedEffect composable. When LaunchedEffect enters the Composition, it launches a coroutine with the block of code passed as a parameter. The coroutine will be cancelled if LaunchedEffect leaves the composition.

> **rememberCoroutineScope: obtain a composition-aware scope to launch a coroutine outside a composable**
>
> As LaunchedEffect is a composable function, it can only be used inside other composable functions. In order to launch a coroutine outside of a composable, but scoped so that it will be automatically canceled once it leaves the composition, use rememberCoroutineScope

More from [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

Answer (score 3):

`rememberCoroutineScope` is a composable function that returns a CoroutineScope bound to the point of the Composition where it's called. The scope will be cancelled when the call leaves the Composition. If you create your own coroutineScope instead of remember you might get `MonotonicFrameClock is not available in this CoroutineContext` error as in question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68398064/jetpack-compose-scrolling-lazycolumn-with-coroutinescope-results-error-a-monoton).

`LaunchedEffect` is a remember under the hood with coroutineScope which runs when it enters composition and when any of its keys change.

```
@Composable
@NonRestartableComposable
@OptIn(InternalComposeApi::class)
fun LaunchedEffect(
    key1: Any?,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val applyContext = currentComposer.applyCoroutineContext
    remember(key1) { LaunchedEffectImpl(applyContext, block) }
}
```

LaunchedEffect is good for launching animations, snackbar, scolls any default suspending function Compose has also another very useful usages is
triggering some events without user interaction

for instance executing a callback only when reaching a certain state without user interactions as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72814682/executing-a-callback-only-when-reaching-a-certain-state-without-user-interaction/72817231#72817231)

```
LaunchedEffect(statementsByYear != null) {

   if (statementsByYear != null) {
         onDataAcquired(statementsByYear!!) 
   } 
}
```

LaunchedEffect gets triggered on composition but as in question since value is null if block condition is not met then when `statementsByYear` is set by api `statementsByYear != null` changes from true to false and if block condition is met and you run the statement.

Or only once inside a Composable using help of ViewModel saving a flag as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72946503/how-can-i-launch-a-function-only-onetime-when-i-use-jetpack-compose/72946980#72946980).

> block of LaunchedEffect(keys) is invoked on composition and when any
> keys change. If you set keys from your ViewModel this LaunchedEffect
> will be launched and you can create a conditional block that checks
> same flag to be true that is contained in ViewModel

```
LaunchedEffect(mViewModel.isLaunched) {
    if(!mViewModel.isLaunched) {
          mViewMode.iniBilling(context as Activity)
          mViewMode.isLaunched = true
    }
}
```

Also conditional blocks enter composition when conditions are met so by wrapping LaunchedEffect with if block you can define when it will enter and exit composition which means canceling job its coroutineScope might be running as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72709495/5457853)

```
if (count > 0 && count <5) {
    // `LaunchedEffect` will cancel and re-launch if
    // `scaffoldState.snackbarHostState` changes
    LaunchedEffect(scaffoldState.snackbarHostState) {
        // Show snackbar using a coroutine, when the coroutine is cancelled the
        // snackbar will automatically dismiss. This coroutine will cancel whenever
        // if statement is false, and only start when statement is true
        // (due to the above if-check), or if `scaffoldState.snackbarHostState` changes.
        scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("count $count")
    }
}
```

This block will enter composition when **count** is bigger than 0 and stay in composition while count is less than 5 but since it's LaunchedEffect it will trigger once but if count reaches 5 faster than Snackbar duration Snackbar gets canceled because block leaves composition.

Answer (score 0):

**LaunchedEffect** launches a ***coroutine*** every time it faces new keys. It's a composable so it's bound to the tree and will be destroyed and cancelled when removed from tree.

**rememberCoroutineScope** creates a ***coroutine scope*** bound to the composable. Then you have a Kotlin coroutine scope that you can use ***anywhere*** to launch coroutines. The scope will be destroyed when the composable that called it is removed from tree.

Where you call **rememberCoroutineScope** and where you use the created scope, depends on your needs and the required lifecycle for the coroutines you launch.

Answer (score 0):

LaunchedEffect as a composable function can only be used inside of another composable function; on the other hand, rememberCoroutineScope allows you to launch a coroutine outside of a composable function

Check this link for further details:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects

Answer (score -3):

**Question 1:**

LaunchEffect
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect

rememberCoroutineScope
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#remembercoroutinescope