# Jetpack Compose scrolling LazyColumn with CoroutineScope results error A MonotonicFrameClock is not available in this CoroutineContext

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-compose

Checking out [this example](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-layouts#5) with list to scroll using state and Coroutines as

```
@Composable
fun ScrollingList() {
    val listSize = 100
    // We save the scrolling position with this state
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
    // We save the coroutine scope where our animated scroll will be executed
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Column {
        Row {
            Button(onClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    // 0 is the first item index
                    scrollState.animateScrollToItem(0)
                }
            }) {
                Text("Scroll to the top")
            }

            Button(onClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    // listSize - 1 is the last index of the list
                    scrollState.animateScrollToItem(listSize - 1)
                }
            }) {
                Text("Scroll to the end")
            }
        }

        LazyColumn(state = scrollState) {
            items(listSize) {
                ImageListItem(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which works fine for suspending function

```
suspend fun animateScrollToItem(
    /*@IntRange(from = 0)*/
    index: Int,
    /*@IntRange(from = 0)*/
    scrollOffset: Int = 0
) {
    doSmoothScrollToItem(index, scrollOffset)
}
```

If i change coroutine scope to

```
val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
```

It returns

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: A MonotonicFrameClock is not
> available in this CoroutineContext. Callers should supply an
> appropriate MonotonicFrameClock using withContext.

What does this mean, and is `rememberCoroutineScope()` only way to provide **coroutineScope** to this function?

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ you want to use `rememberCoroutineScope()`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake not because i would not use it, just curios what that error is about  and if there are any other ways to provide **coroutineScope**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As animateScrollToItem is composable function it needs to be called within the scope of Composition.

[As documentation states](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#remembercoroutinescope)

> rememberCoroutineScope is a composable function that returns a CoroutineScope bound to the point of the Composition where it's called. The scope will be cancelled when the call leaves the Composition.